# AddTwoInts example with minus

Tags: rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably very simple and dumb question. I have code similar to AddTwoInts example. How to enter negative values there?

```
tonu@hp:~/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi$ rosservice call phippi_motors -0.2 0.2
Usage: rosservice call /service [args...]

rosservice: error: no such option: -0
tonu@hp:~/tyros/phippi/ros/phippi$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9663/addtwoints-example-with-minus/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This tool uses the YAML commandline syntax described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine).

To fix this particular problem, you would separate your arguments from the command's options using `--`. For example, `rosservice call phippi_motors -- -0.2 0.2` should work.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rikki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1114/rikki/) on 2012-02-13**:
Uff, I was looking for this. You have just resolved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved.

```
tonu@hp:~$ rosservice call phippi_motors '{a: 1, b: 2}'
result: Go done
tonu@hp:~$ rosservice call phippi_motors '{a: -0.1, b: 0}'
result: Go done
tonu@hp:~$
```

---

Originally posted by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) with karma: 161 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2